# Syncfusion.Pdf.Base and Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable - different assemblies in one codeShareProject

Tags: .net-assembly, portability, radix, syncfusion

I have one core project, type of CodeShareProject in Visual, which other projects use.

Other projects are: Xamarin Mobile App and WinForms on desktop.

Xamarin App use assembly Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable (from Syncfusion.Xamarin.Pdf) to generate pdfs, and desktop app use assembly Syncfusion.Pdf.Base(from Syncfusion.WinForms.Pdf).

Then I have conflicts, because for example PdfDocument is in both: Syncfusion.Pdf.Base and Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yql59.png)

How to resolve this? Someone knows? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can overcome the mentioned issue by adding "Alias" for the dll "Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.dll". Please refer the below code for your reference,

.CSProj file changes

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliases"BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences"> 
<ItemGroup> 
  <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable'">
   <Aliases>global,syncfusionPortable</Aliases>    
  </ReferencePath>    
</ItemGroup>    
</Target>
```

Add the below namespaces in your class file:

```
extern alias syncfusionPortable;  
using syncfusionPortable::Syncfusion.Pdf;  
using syncfusionPortable::Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;
```

While adding the above solution, the reported conflicts will not occurs. We have created the simple sample to illustrate this and please find the download link from below,

[Download the sample here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PdfSample354783967)